# Problem with function that checks whether an entered string contains numbers

Tags: c, assert

I have created a function that checks if a string contains numbers. If it contains anything other than a number (decimals are allowed) it returns false. I'm running asserts on it and it fails when the string is `6.e` or `a` (or any number/single letter combination).

I can't see any obvious errors so any help would be appreciated.

Checker function:

```
bool numCheck (Program *p)
{
   int i, len = strlen(p->wds[p->cnt]) - 1;

   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if ((p->wds[p->cnt][i] != '.') && (p->wds[p->cnt][i] < '0' ||
          p->wds[p->cnt][i] > '9')) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Asserts being run, :

```
strcpy(pr->wds[0], "3.9");
assert(numCheck(pr) == true); /* pass */
strcpy(pr->wds[0], "gh");
assert(numCheck(pr) == false); /* pass */
strcpy(pr->wds[0], "6.6.6.6");
assert(numCheck(pr) == false); /* fails but shouldn't as only 1 decimal point allowed */
strcpy(pr->wds[0], "6.e");
assert(numCheck(pr) == false); /* fail */
strcpy(pr->wds[0], "a");
assert(numCheck(pr) == false);  /* fail */
```

Comment: Well, there's absolutely nowhere you check if you have multiple dots.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might be interested in learning about the [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) function.

Comment: Furthermore, use `isdigit()` instead of own constructs

Comment: What is `Program`?

Comment: And the problem could be somewhere else in the code. Please fix a [mre]

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1 from the string length used in the loop? I assume that's one of your problems. As the man page says "The strlen() function returns the number of characters that *precede* the terminating NUL character"